# How to add "you save" option in the shopping cart of opencart?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart, opencart-module

I am trying to create a you save option in the shopping cart of opencart.com. I have done the same feature of you save to be displayed in the product page using vqmod. But i am finding it difficult to do it for the shopping cart. here is my vqmod code for adding you save option in the product page.

```
<modification>
    <id><![CDATA[@tik Savings Note]]></id>
    <version><![CDATA[1.1]]></version>
    <vqmver><![CDATA[2.1.7]]></vqmver>
    <author><![CDATA[OC2PS]]></author>
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before" offset="2" error="log"><![CDATA[<?php if ($tax) { ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[<br /><span class="you-save" style="color:red;"><?php echo $text_yousave; ?> <?php echo $yousave; ?></span>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/language/english/product/product.php">
       <operation>
            <search position="replace" error="log"><![CDATA[// Entry]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$_['text_yousave']        = 'You save:';// Entry]]></add>
       </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" error="log"><![CDATA[$data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
                 $data['text_yousave'] = $this->language->get('text_yousave');]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" error="log"><![CDATA[$data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                $data['yousave'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price']-$product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                $data['yousavepercent'] = round(($product_info['price']-$product_info['special'])*100/$product_info['price'],0);]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" error="log"><![CDATA[$special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    $yousave = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price']-$result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    $yousavepercent = round(($result['price']-$result['special'])*100/$result['price'],0);]]></add>
        </operation>        
    </file>
</modification>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes some of them have been answered. i wasnt aware about closing the topic. ill make sure that i mark the answers closed once i find the answer. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome Susan. I wasn't pressuring you here, it's just how Stack rolls. Others may feel tempted to submit more answers because they think the question's still open. *Cheers*